# shared variable between to node modules

Tags: node.js, module, share

I've an issue.
I need to generate a random number in one node module, and then to use it in other module.

How can I share it between modules without regenerate it for each require I do

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to generate a random number once and then use it across modules right? It is simple. Just export the random number from the module that it is generated from and require it in the module that you want to use it from. Here is the code

```
exports.myRandomNumber = 112938;

var number = require("./myFile").myRandomNumber;
```